# Auto Layout in xib - Subview's height proportional to space between navigation bar and tab bar

Tags: autolayout

How would you do this when working in an xib. (Adding constraints programmatically is fine, but having any hardcoded value anywhere for the navigation bar or status bar is not.)

There is a sub-view whose relative height I want to be proportional to the vertical space between the top layout guide and bottom layout guide.

For example, in the below image - The blue portion's height needs to be proportional to the vertical space between the navigation bar and the bottom tab bar (if any).

[image]

PS - Once again, its an xib and not a storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this question, here is how I did it.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {  NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.subviewInQuestion
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:nil
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:0.5*(self.view.frame.size.height - [self.topLayoutGuide length] - [self.bottomLayoutGuide length])];
heightConstraint.identifier = @"ID_5";
[self.view addConstraint:heightConstraint];

[self.view setNeedsLayout]; }
```